# Batch user's environment variables not getting set in su -c

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, su

I'm trying to set up my /etc/rc.local to automatically start up a process on reboot as another user. For some reason, the .bash_rc for this user does not seem to be getting initialized.

Here's the command I added to /etc/rc.local :

```
sudo su -l batchuser -c "/home/batchuser/app/run_prod.sh &"
```

this didn't work, so I also tried this:

```
sudo su -l batchuser -c ". /home/batchuser/.profile; /home/batchuser/app/run_prod.sh &"
```

`run_prod.sh` just starts up a python script. The python script fails because it references modules which are in a python path which gets initialized in the .bash_rc

---

EDIT: it works when I do this

```
sudo su -l batchuser -c "export PYTHONPATH=/my/python/path; /home/batchuser/app/run_prod.sh &"
```

Why does this work and not the statement above? How come the .bashrc is not getting initialized?

Comment: What are the sudoers(5) settings for `batchuser` (obtainable with `sudo -l -U batchuser`)?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this same problem.  I can't fully explain the behavior, but I ended up doing this type of thing:

```
sudo $PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH the_command
```

or more specifically for your case,

```
sudo $PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH su -l batchuser -c /home/batchuser/app/run_prod.sh &"
```

Does that work for you?  If it does, you may find it doesn't return immediately like you expect it to.  You may need to move the `&` outside the quotes so it applies to the sudo command.